# Can I do multiple functions in one Lightning Component Controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, helper

I have tried to put multiple functions into the one Component Controller unsuccessfully. I then created a helper class that the Component Controller calls and will run the different methods. This was unsuccessful as well. The error I am getting is either: `Uncaught Action failed: c:RealEstateComponent$controller$newMortgage [cmp is not defined]` when I attempt to pass the Helper class a parameter -- or -- `Uncaught Action failed: c:RealEstateComponent$controller$newMortgage [Cannot read property 'get' of undefined]`

It can not understand the .get() method and I am not sure how to move forward with putting in multiple JS functions in either the Controller or the Helper class. Could someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

COMPONENT

```
({
"newHome" : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.newHome(cmp);
    /*var action = cmp.get("c.newHomeAPEX");
    action.setParams({ 
    "name" : cmp.find("houseNameInput").get("v.value"), 
    "bed" : cmp.find("bedInput").get("v.value"), 
    "bath" : cmp.find("bathInput").get("v.value"), 
    "state" : cmp.find("stateInput").get("v.value"), 
    "city" : cmp.find("cityInput").get("v.value"), 
    "zipCode" : cmp.find("zipCodeInput").get("v.value"), 
    "listingPrice" : cmp.find("listingPriceInput").get("v.value"), 
    "address" : cmp.find("houseAddressInput").get("v.value") });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('it worked!');
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert('incomplete');
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);*/
},        

"newEscrow" : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.newEscrow(cmp);
    /*var action = cmp.get("c.newEscrowAPEX");
    action.setParams({ 
    "name" : cmp.find("escrowNameInput").get("v.value"), 
    "mortgage" : cmp.find("mortgageCompanyInput").get("v.value"), 
    "cost" : cmp.find("escrowCostInput").get("v.value"), 
    "yearFounded" : cmp.find("foundedInput").get("v.value")
     });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('it worked!');
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert('incomplete');
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);*/
},        

"newMortgage" : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.newMortgage(cmp);
    /*var action = cmp.get("c.newMortgageAPEX");
    action.setParams({ 
    "name" : cmp.find("mortgageNameInput").get("v.value"), 
    "loanOfficer" : cmp.find("loanOfficerInput").get("v.value"), 
    "loanAmount" : cmp.find("loanAmountInput").get("v.value"), 
    "underwriter" : cmp.find("underwriterInput").get("v.value"),
    "escrowName" : cmp.find("escrowInput").get("v.value")
     });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('it worked!');
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert('incomplete');
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);*/
}   
})
```

HELPER

```
({
newHome : function(cmp) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.newHomeAPEX");
    action.setParams({ 
    "name" : cmp.find("houseNameInput").get("v.value"), 
    "bed" : cmp.find("bedInput").get("v.value"), 
    "bath" : cmp.find("bathInput").get("v.value"), 
    "state" : cmp.find("stateInput").get("v.value"), 
    "city" : cmp.find("cityInput").get("v.value"), 
    "zipCode" : cmp.find("zipCodeInput").get("v.value"), 
    "listingPrice" : cmp.find("listingPriceInput").get("v.value"), 
    "address" : cmp.find("houseAddressInput").get("v.value") });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('it worked!');
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert('incomplete');
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}, 

newEscrow: function(cmp){
    var action = cmp.get("c.newEscrowAPEX");
    action.setParams({ 
    "name" : cmp.find("escrowNameInput").get("v.value"), 
    "mortgage" : cmp.find("mortgageCompanyInput").get("v.value"), 
    "cost" : cmp.find("escrowCostInput").get("v.value"), 
    "yearFounded" : cmp.find("foundedInput").get("v.value")
     });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('it worked!');
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert('incomplete');
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}, 

newMortgage : function(cmp){
    var action = cmp.get("c.newMortgageAPEX");
    action.setParams({ 
    "name" : cmp.find("mortgageNameInput").get("v.value"), 
    "loanOfficer" : cmp.find("loanOfficerInput").get("v.value"), 
    "loanAmount" : cmp.find("loanAmountInput").get("v.value"), 
    "underwriter" : cmp.find("underwriterInput").get("v.value"),
    "escrowName" : cmp.find("escrowInput").get("v.value")
     });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('it worked!');
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert('incomplete');
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

APEX

```
public class RealEstateClass {
@AuraEnabled
public static String newHomeAPEX(String city, String state, Integer zipCode, String name, String address, Integer bed, Integer bath, Double listingPrice){
    system.debug('values:: ' + name);
    Real_Estate__c re = new Real_Estate__c(Zip_Code__c = zipCode, State__c = state, City__c=city, Name = name, Street_Address__c = address, Bed__c = bed, Bath__c = bath, Listing_Price__c = listingPrice);
    insert re;
    system.debug('re: ' + re);
    return ('Hello from the server, ' + name);
}

@AuraEnabled
public static void newEscrowAPEX(Id mortgage, Date yearFounded, String name, Double cost){
    system.debug('values:: ' + name);
    Escrow__c es = new Escrow__c(Mortgage_Company__c = mortgage, Year_Founded__c = yearFounded, Name =name, Cost__c = cost);
    insert es;
    system.debug('es: ' + es);
}

@AuraEnabled
public static void newMortgageAPEX(Id loanOfficer, String name, Double loanAmount, Id underwriter, Id escrowName){
    system.debug('values:: ' + name);
    Mortgage_Company__c mort = new Mortgage_Company__c(Name = name, Loan_Amount__c = loanAmount, Loan_Officer__c =loanOfficer, Underwriter__c = underwriter, Escrow__c = escrowName);
    insert mort;
    system.debug('mort: ' + mort);
}
}
```

COMPONENT INPUT

```
<!--Escrow-->
    <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Escrow Name</label>
        <ui:inputText class="form-control" aura:id="escrowNameInput" />
    </div>
    <!--<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Mortgage Company</label>
        <ui:inputText class="form-control" aura:id="mortgageCompanyInput" />
    </div>-->
    <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Cost</label>
        <ui:inputText class="form-control" aura:id="escrowCostInput" />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Year Founded</label>
        <ui:inputText class="form-control" aura:id="foundedInput" />
    </div>
    <ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.newEscrow}" class="btn" />
<hr></hr>
```

COMPONENT OUTPUT

```
             <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Escrow Company</span></th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <aura:iteration items="{!v.getEscrow}" var="e">
                 <tr>
                     <td>{!e.Name}</td> 
                     <td><button class="slds-button"><a href="{!e.Id}" target="_blank"> Edit</a></button></td>
                 </tr>
             </aura:iteration>
         </tbody>
         </table>
```

Comment: i don't see any aura:id with loanOfficerInput or mortgageNameInput which is causing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your helper, modify the function definitions to accept the component as a parameter, which you're already passing from the controller:

`newHome : function() {` to `newHome : function(cmp) {`

and

`newEscrow: function(){` to `newEscrow: function(cmp){`

For the last one `newMortgage : function(){` you're not passing anything to it but then inside the function you're trying to reference `cmp`... Change both, the controller - `helper.newMortgage(cmp);` and the helper `newMortgage : function(cmp){`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately I have already tried this, and the error I get back is: `Uncaught Action failed::RealEstateComponent$controller$newMortgage [cmp is not defined]`

Comment: I can't see where that's called from. Please update your markup where you're calling the `newMortgage` function

Comment: I am calling it in my Component.  It is the third method down

Comment: You've defined it in the component's controller, but I can't see where in the actual component (.cmp) you're calling this method.